# Can't access file in Android External Storage

Tags: android, file, xamarin.android, storage, external

I'm using Xamarin Forms for a photo capture app and using James' [Media Plugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin) PCL to capture photo using the device camera.

I realize that, for every photo, it creates a file in
 `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.myapp/files/Pictures`

(and I can provide a subdirectory within Pictures folder and the name of the file). What I want to do is delete all these files the next time my app starts up.

Since I'm only focused on the Android version, I've set up a dependency service call to locally delete the file (which I thought was trivial) but for some reasons I simply can NOT find that file programmatically or through ADB shell.

When I plug my device in for USB file transfer on windows computer, I can see the photos I want to delete in 
`Computer\Moto G (4)\Internal shared storage\Android\data\com.myapp\files\Pictures`

But I can't get to these files through code or shell. In code, I'm getting the path through

```
Forms.Context.GetExternalFilesDir(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryPictures).AbsolutePath
```

which gives me the path

```
/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.myapp/files/Pictures
```

which I think is the path where my files SHOULD be. But it's come up blank. Whether I try `System.IO` or `Java.IO`, the directory comes up empty and `file.delete()` or `System.IO.File.Delete(path)` doesn't work for me.

tldr; What does

```
Computer\Moto G (4)\Internal shared storage\Android\data\com.myapp\files\Pictures
```

translate to in terms of actual physical path in Android OS which we can list from ADB Shell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a false negative. I was looking at the files through Windows Explorer and for some reason, Windows kept showing me those files even after they were deleted. Obviously, the reason I couldn't se those files through ADB Shell or from within Android File Manager was because those files were never there.

Forms.Context.GetExternalFilesDir(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryPictures).AbsolutePath

gives me

/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.myapp/files/Pictures

which is the same as

Computer\Moto G (4)\Internal shared storage\Android\data\com.myapp\files\Pictures

Both System.IO.File.Delete(path) and new Java.IO.File(dir, children[i]).Delete(); methods work fine. It's just that windows chooses to keep showing the empty "ghost" files.

This issue has apparently been raised before to no answer: [Programatically deleted files still show up in Windows Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8097768/programatically-deleted-files-still-show-up-in-windows-explorer)

Answer (score 0):

> What I want to do is delete all these files the next time my app starts up.

Try using the following code, it works fine on my side :

```
public void DeleteFolder()
{
    var path = Forms.Context.GetExternalFilesDir(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryPictures).AbsolutePath;

    Java.IO.File directory = new Java.IO.File(path);

    if (directory.IsDirectory)
    {
        foreach (Java.IO.File child in directory.ListFiles())
        {
            deleteRecursive(child);
        }
    }
    directory.Delete();
}
```